# Is there a website or online database of what policies different politicians have voted for?

Tags: democracy, reference-request, transparency, voting-records

Ideally I think there should be an accessible website where people can make informed decisions on who they want to vote for based on the past actions of politicians. If this does not exist, any information about databases or APIs with this kind of information would be appreciated.

I'm especially looking for a site concerning UK MPs, as that's where I live, but would appreciate information on any similar databases or websites around the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hansard](http://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/hansard/) is the official report of the proceedings of both houses of parliament. The votes that come from this are accessible through the [parliament.uk](http://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/business-papers/commons/votes-and-proceedings/#session=62738&year=2013&month=3&day=18) website. Unfortunately, they're broken down by date. It is often easier to read them both in tandem as the votes can be a little confusing unless you know exactly what you're looking for.

There are two further websites that use Hansard under licence to present the data in a more user-friendly manner:

http://www.theyworkforyou.com/
http://www.publicwhip.org.uk/

Answer (score 4):

[govtrack.us](http://www.govtrack.us/) is a good resource for checking which politicians voted for which bill(in the United States)

You can use it to check specifically which legislators voted for a particular bill

You can also track statistics and votes of individual representatives, although I haven't explored this feature too terribly deeply

[For instance, here's the page for Nancy Pelosi](http://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/nancy_pelosi/400314)

Comment: Thanks, that's a great resource for US citizens. I have sent them a tweet asking if they know of a UK version.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer If you hear back and there is a UK version, feel free to post an answer here telling us about it. Answering your own question is perfectly fine, if you have a good answer for it.

Comment: They have replied saying there is no UK version that they know of, but their source code is on GitHub - https://github.com/govtrack/govtrack.us-web/commits/master - so I might looking into making one :)

Comment: Got a follow up reply from @govtrack, directing me to [They Work For You](http://www.theyworkforyou.com/) which seems like a fairly good version of what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking state level or people running for office at Federal with only state experience, you can look at the state legislature pages as many, like Iowa, have bill tracking tools.

https://www.legis.iowa.gov/Legislation/BillTracking/billTrackingTools.aspx